# Call a method on page pop

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm pushing a new route like so in my app

```dart
Navigator.of(context)
          .push<void>(
        FilterTypesPage.routeFullScreen(context),
      ).then(
        (value) {
          log('PAGGGE POPPED');
        },
      ),
```

```
  static Route routeFullScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        settings: const RouteSettings(name: routeName),
        builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
              value: BlocProvider.of<FeatureBloc>(context),
              child: const FilterTypesPage(),
            ),
        fullscreenDialog: true);
  }
```

for some reason `log('PAGGGE POPPED');` doesn't get called on page close

I'd like to trigger a bloc event or a function when I close this page

Answer (score 1):

You should just call

```dart
Navigator.pop(context, someData);
```

from your `RouteSettings` where `someData` is the data you want to pass from the `RouteSettings` to the former page.

Then from your former page, you can perform your event handling inside the `then` block. The `value` inside the `then` block is the data that was passed from the `RouteSettings` page.

Alternatively, you can also use `async-await` instead of `then` in your former page.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final someData = await Navigator.of(cotext).push(.....);
  // Now perform your event handling which will be invoked after you pop `RouteSettings` page.
}
```

Comment: someData has type `Future<void>` how can I use its value ?

Comment: `someData` is the value that you passed from one screen to another when popping the page. Why are you passing `void` from one screen to another? Doesn't really make sense..